# doesnt work in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

here is my javasript:

```
            function random_imglink() {
            var myimages = [
                {image: "/documents/templates/projedepo/banner/canon.jpg", url: "/index.cfm?fuseaction=objects2.detail_product&product_id=612&stock_id=612"},
                {image: "/documents/templates/projedepo/banner/indigovision.jpg", url: "http://www.url2.com"}
            ];

            var ry=Math.floor(Math.random()*myimages.length);

            var randomImage = myimages[ry];

            var randomImageLink = '<a id="random_link" href="' + randomImage.url + '"><img style="z-index:1;position:absolute; left:70px; top:360px;" border="0" align="absmiddle" src="/documents/templates/projedepo/banner/daha_fazlasi.jpg" /></a><img id="random_img" src="'+randomImage.image+'" height="420" width="964" />';
            document.getElementById("image2").innerHTML = randomImageLink;
            }
 $(function() {
  $(".image2").click(function() {
  var image = $(this).attr("rel");
    var rel = $('#random_img').hide().fadeIn('slow').attr('src');
    $('#random_img').attr('src', image);

  var randomLink = $(this).attr("href");
  $('#random_link').attr('href',randomLink);

    var image2 = $('#random_img').attr('src');
    $("#thumb2 a img").removeClass("open");
    $("#thumb2 a[rel='" + image2 + "'] img").addClass("open");
    return false;
  });
 }); 

 $(document).ready(function() {
   var image2 = $('#random_img').attr('src');
   $("#thumb2 a[rel='" + image2 + "'] img").addClass("open");
 });
                random_imglink()
```

Here is my html:

```
<div id="slider_container">    
<div id="image2">Here is written my sript</div>
<div id="thumb2">

<a href="/index.cfm?fuseaction=objects2.detail_product&product_id=612&stock_id=612" rel="/documents/templates/projedepo/banner/canon.jpg" class="image2" ><img title="Canon" class="slider_thumb" src="/documents/templates/bilgiteknolojileri/images/t_flash/t1.png" border="0"/></a>
<a href="http://www.url2.com" rel="/documents/templates/projedepo/banner/indigovision.jpg" class="image2"><img title="IndigoVision" class="slider_thumb" src="/documents/templates/bilgiteknolojileri/images/t_flash/t2.png" border="0"/></a>

</div></div>
```

IN Internet Explorer, NOT in Firefox or Opera,
at first it works fine, the random image is displayed and thumbnails are ok, but when i click the thumbnail, the random image turns in frame with overflows, like this: http://vteam.net.ru/_fr/11/1923928.jpg

Comment: why? what is wrong here? i can't understand what is the problem with script, so that it displayed like this in IE

Comment: @venom questions like "here's my code, it's not working" aren't usually well-received.  It would help if you could narrow things down further, give more context to the problem, post any errors, take more time with the question, etc.  Remember, you're asking people to spend time helping you -- we need more thorough investigation from you, first.

Comment: isnt it enough inf about the problem? everything works fine in all the browsers, but not in IE, the script gives random image and link, then there are the thumbnails, when u click em the image is changed, but not in IE

Comment: Are you sure that the thing shown in the image is a frame and not anotzer element? If It's not a frame your css will be important too.

Comment: actually i dont know for certain what element is displayed there, but my css is not big, ill add it now

Comment: Surprising how many people prefer to downvote a question(I think this is a question, can't see what else it should be) instead of giving an related answer.

Comment: @ifaour: yep, here is it: http://jsfiddle.net/5jRjn/

Comment: Everything works fine there(if I choose jQuery instead of mootools as library on the fiddle) in IE 6,7 & 8, can't see anything like shown on the image. Maybe you'll have to clear IE's cache.

Comment: As Dr.Molle said, everything is working just fine [see it](http://jsfiddle.net/ifaour/NFcuS/embedded/result/) r u having any problems on this link?. Also it could be the ur browser cache or some other CSS file (or code)..Anyway, r u trying to make a tab effect? because the way you are doing it is way complex than it should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only suspect thing I see is this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var image2 = $('#random_img').attr('src');
   $("#thumb2 a[rel='" + image2 + "'] img").addClass("open");
 });
                random_imglink()
```

In your HTML-source you wrote

```
    <div id="image2">Here is written my sript</div>
```

...so I assume that the script is placed there. This can be a problem.Replace the code above with

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       var image2 = $('#random_img').attr('src');
       $("#thumb2 a[rel='" + image2 + "'] img").addClass("open");
       random_imglink();
     });
```

(Move the call of random_imglink() into the ready-function). Otherwise it's called immediately, but there will be an element manipulated (#image2) which is not closed yet, what may result in an error in MSIE.